# Losing session in Jsp-Servlet based application after domain redirection

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have created a Java Web Application based on simple JSP-Servlet. I have one dedicated server with static IP(example ip - 102.30.101.5). On port 8080, IIS is running & on port 9090 Apache Tomcat is running. I have deployed my web app(demoapp) on port 9090(Apache Tomcat). 
I have one domain (example domain - example.com or www.example.com), redirect this domain to my static IP using A-Field ie www.example.com to 102.30.101.5

In IIS, I have configured(URL Rewrite option in IIS) the incoming URL request as, if www.example.com is incoming request then redirect it to port 9090 on which my web application is running(Apache Tomcat).

After doing all this, I faced one big problem.

When I am accessing my application using IP ie 102.30.101.5:9090/demoapp, its working properly.
But when I am accessing through www.example.com, for each request, new sessionid is created.
Ex. for same browser, its creating different sessionid on each request.
Because of this, I am not able to maintain the session of logging user.
Also its affecting for Search Engine Optimization.

I guess, its redirection problem, but exactly don't know what's the problem.

Please help as soon as.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your sessions are maintained through cookies. A cookie is always limited to a specific host name - and an IP address qualifies as a totally different host name. Whenever you change host names, it's fully expected to loose the session, because that's how cookies (the most used session identifier storage) work.

There's a way of adding session identifiers to the URL, but this is prone to the session appearing in external server's logs if you link to external servers, thus it's a potential session leakage and not recommended unless you *absolutely* know what you're doing.

You should configure your redirection in a way that it redirects whenever someone contacts your server through an unintended hostname or just the IP address, before a session has ever been created.

Comment: Thank You Sir @olaf-kock I also tried other Session Tracking methods but getting same output.

Comment: Just do the early and immediate redirect whenever someone comes to another than the standard host name and you're set. No more need to fiddle around and try other techniques. As I said above: They have known problems and *absolutely* knowing about these problems is a *real* precondition. The italics on *"absolutely"* is on purpose.

Comment: Apology for extremely late reply but issue has been closed after adding below line in web.xml: 

**<http-only>true</http-only>**